# How to fix token issue with webchat

Tags: php, botframework, token

The bot framework api to generate a directline token results in a token that webchat cannot handle.

Recently I noticed the webchat on my website was not able to make a directline connection anymore. Using the directline secret results in a working webchat. Using the bot framework api to generate a very long token (816 characters) that webchat cannot handle (resulting in a message like unable to connect. This used to work just fine but now its broke (and nothing changed as far as I know)

I use some PHP to call the api and get a token:

```
<?php
    $botSecret = 'DIRECLINE SECRET';
    $response = wp_remote_get( 'https://webchat.botframework.com/api/tokens',    array( 'headers' => 'Authorization: BotConnector ' . $botSecret ) );
if( is_array($response) ) {
  $header = $response['headers'];
  $token = $response['body'];
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
           var webChatToken = <?php echo $token; ?>;
       </script>
```

And Html\Javascript to show the webchat client

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="webchat" role="main"></div>   
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
    <script>  
       const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
         if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
           dispatch({
             type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
             payload: {
               name: 'webchat/join',
               value: { language: window.navigator.language }
             }
           });
         }
         return next(action);
       });
        window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token: webChatToken }),
        store,
        styleOptions: {
        },
        userID: 'N/A',
        username: 'Web Chat User',
        locale: 'nl-NL'
      }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would expect a shorter token or at least a token that can be used to use webchat

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue? Can you provide more information about the error? What was the error code you saw when Web Chat failed to connect?

Comment: I am afraid I am. The error is (translated from Dutch) ‘Unable to make connection’ I am now using a workaround by using the direct-line secret to connect

Comment: I don't see any glaring issues with your code, and I was able to request a token from the endpoint you used above to connect to my bot. I would recommend taking a look at [Generating a DirectLine Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#generate-token)  and giving that a try.

Comment: Willco. Tnx for helping out

Comment: I read the doc and tried alternative implementations. Didn't get it to work. What was the length of your token (i get token of 816 characters) and did you succesfully connect to your bot via the [webchat client?](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) Thank you

Comment: Are you using a Web Chat or a DirectLine secret? Using the endpoint you mentioned in your question and a DirectLine secret, I get a 403 error and a much longer token - 825 characters. However, when I use a Web Chat secret, I get a shorter token that works fine. What error code are you getting - you can check the console by hitting F12? Does it fail with all browsers? Do you have a conversation Id you can share so we can check out logs?

Comment: You nailed it. Thanks man! I was using the DirectLine secret. I disabled my webchat channel because it ended up in Google's index. For some reason I used the DirectLine secret afterwards. I enabled Webchat again, used that secret and everything is ok. Thanks again.

Comment: Were you getting a 403 error before?

Comment: Dont know. The webchat client showed a message that he/she couldn’t connect. Did not check console. Would you like me to do so?

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, I would appreciate it. I'm trying to work through another issue that might be related.

Comment: Ok. Tomorrow I will (am in European timezone)

Comment: Thank you - I appreciate it!

Comment: Using a directline  secret in a webchatclient results in a long token wit a length of > 800 (the length varies) and a 403 error translated into a Unable to Connect message in the client. Tested it on W10 Chrome and Edge.

Comment: Thanks again! Very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BotFramework Development Team just deployed an update that allows you to use a DirectLine secret with the Web Chat endpoint, so you can now use either a DirectLine or a WebChat secret to connect Web Chat to your bot.

```
const res = await fetch('https://webchat.botframework.com/api/tokens', {
    method: 'GET', 
    headers: { 
        Authorization: 'BotConnector <WEB_CHAT_SECRET | DIRECT_LINE_SECRET>'
    } 
});

const token = await res.json();

window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token })
}, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Using a directline secret in a webchatclient results in a long token wit a length of > 800 (the length varies) and a 403 error translated into a Unable to Connect message in the client. x. Allthough the fact that the method to create a connection is called 'createDirectLine', webchat clients still need webchat secrets.